# I am trying to make an array[ i ] 'glow' in order assigned. Why is my code not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to make a simon game. I'm trying to use the `glowInOrder()` function to make the divs glow in the order of the array. Unfortunately only the first div in the array glows, not the others that follow. (When I say 'glow', I simply mean add effect that looks like glow using CSS.) I suspect the issue is in the `glowInOrder()` function, but i am unable to find the issue.

Here's my code (also [on CodePen](https://codepen.io/kevinalexanderduran/pen/praPEg)):

```js
var colorArray = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink"];
var player = [];
var computer = [];
var round = 0;
var randomOrder;
var myColor;
var chosenColor;

//--------------------------------------------------------//


function makeGlow(yolo) {

  $(yolo).addClass('hover');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(yolo).removeClass('hover');
  }, 300);

}


//--------------------------------------------------------//


function makeGlowTwo(yolo) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(yolo).addClass('hover');
  }, 500);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(yolo).removeClass('hover');
  }, 800);
}


//--------------------------------------------------------//


function newGame() {
  player = [];
  computer = [];
  round = 0;
}


//---------------------------------------------------------//


function playerChoice() {
  $('.all').on('click', function(e) {
    player.push(e.target.id);
    makeGlow(this);
  });
};


//---------------------------------------------------------//


function computerChoice() {
  randomOrder = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length);
  myColor = colorArray[randomOrder];
  computer.push(myColor);
  chosenColor = "#" + myColor;
  makeGlowTwo(chosenColor);
}


//--------------------------------------------------------//


function newRound() {
  round++;
  glowInOrder();
}


//---------------------------------------------------------//


function glowInOrder() {
  //computerChoice();//this may not work take out if you find it doesn't
  var i = 1;
  var moves = setInterval(function() {
    makeGlowTwo(computer[i]);
    i++;
    if (i >= computer.length) {
      clearInterval(moves);
    }
  }, 400)

}


//---------------------------------------------------------//


function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length)
    return false;
  for (var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}


//---------------------------------------------------------//
$(document).ready(function() {
  newGame();
  playerChoice();
  computerChoice();
  $('.all').on('click', function() {
    if (arraysEqual(computer, player)) {
      alert('yes');
      glowInOrder();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.all {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#red {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#blue {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}

#green {
  border: 5px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#yellow {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#pink {
  border: 5px solid pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.middleRow {
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 110px;
}

.gameContainer {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gameContainer">
    <div class="topRow">
      <div id="red" class="all"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="middleRow">
      <div id="green" class="all"></div>
      <div id="blue" class="all"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomRow">
      <div id="yellow" class="all"></div>
      <div id="pink" class="all"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Instead of CodePen, please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) to create a runnable example of your problem. **Edit:** I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues that jump out:

1. You're only calling `computerChoice` once, and it adds only one entry to the array. So you have only one entry in `computer` at index `0`.
2. Your `glowInOrder` function starts with `i` set to 1, which doesn't match any entry in your array. And naturally stops when you do the `i >= computer.length` check.

You need to ensure that `computer` has the correct number of entries (I'm guessing 5), and you need to start with `i = 0` to start with the first one in your `glowInOrder`.

There are probably other logic issues in the code, but that's what's going on in relation to what you asked about. If you work through it in a debugger (there's one built into your browser) you'll be able to sort the other issues out.

Comment: Thank yoi for your help tj. I fixed i=0 in my glowInOrder function but that did not help. I've tried using the debugger to console log the computer array and the player array it seems Like the outputs are correct? Both arrays are identical whenever I begin to play. They both also accept new colors in the way they are supposed to. Maybe I'm missing a crucial piece of logic. But I've been stuck on this specific logical problem for  20 days